# Locators in Manipulate not moving properly

Tags: dynamic, manipulate

I thought a simple Mathematica kerning machine (for adjusting the space between characters) would be interesting, but I'm having trouble with the locators. (There are a number of other questions related to this, and I've read the answers, but as yet without finding a solution, or understanding them that well.)

```
 Manipulate[
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[points],
   text = "Wolfram";
   fonts = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]];
   Column[{
     Button["Export", Export["/tmp/t.png", g]],
     g = Graphics[{
          MapIndexed[
          Text[Style[#1, FontSize -> fontsize, FontFamily -> font], 
            points[[First[#2]]]] &, Characters[text]]}, ImageSize -> 500]
     }]],
  {points, {Table[{ x, 0}, {x, 1, Length[Characters[text]]}]}, 
    ControlType -> None},
  {fontsize , Table[x, {x, 96, 256, 12}]} ,
  {font, fonts}
 ]
```

(The font menu gets populated once you use it.)

[image: kerning machine]

I want to be able to slide the letters right or left (but not up or down), but at the moment they don't move like they're supposed to.

### The solution

Thanks to the fine answers, I've got something useful working. There are some kludges and hacks too, and some problems still to be ironed out (string length needs to be dynamic, 'canvas' needs resizing, and so on), but this is excellent for now.

```
With[{fonts = FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]]},
 DynamicModule[{kernedText, points},
  points = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, Length[Characters[text]] + 10}];
  Column[{
    (* input *)
    InputField[Dynamic[text], String],
    (* main panel *)
    Panel@LocatorPane[
      Dynamic[
       points, (points = ReplacePart[#, {{_, 2} -> 0}]) &], 
      Dynamic[kernedText = 
        Graphics[{MapIndexed[
           Text[Style[#1, FontSize -> fontsize, FontFamily -> font], 
             points[[First[#2]]]] &, Characters[text]]}, 
         PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + Length[Characters[text]]}, Automatic}, 
         Background -> None, ImageSize -> 800]], Appearance -> None],
    (* controls *)
    Row[
     {
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[fontsize], Table[x, {x, 72, 416, 12}]],
      PopupMenu[Dynamic[font], fonts],
      Button["Export", 
       Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", 
          "KernedText.png"}], kernedText], 
       ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}]
      }]
    }, Left]]]
```

[image: final]

I realised that the locator dots didn't need to be showing - just click on the characters. The result can be compared to the unkerned version:

```
Text[Style[text, 192, FontFamily -> "Palatino"]]
```

[image: unkerned]

For me, this area of Mathematica (Manipulate/Dynamic) is gradually becoming less confusing (but only gradually).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just an addendum to jVincent's answer. In order to constrain the letters/locators to a horizontal line, you need to use the second argument of `Dynamic`. The following modified version of jVincent's answer adds the needed constraint:

```
With[{text = "Wolfram", fontsize = 96, font = "Georgia"},
   DynamicModule[{chars, kernedText, points},
      chars = Length[Characters[text]];
      points = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, chars}]; 
      Column[{Panel@
         LocatorPane[
            Dynamic[points, (points = ReplacePart[#, {{_, 2} -> 0}]) &], 
            Dynamic[kernedText = 
               Graphics[
                  {
                  MapIndexed[
                     Text[Style[#1, FontSize -> fontsize,
                        FontFamily -> font], points[[First[#2]]]]&,
                     Characters[text]]
                  }, 
                  PlotRange -> {{0, 1 + chars}, Automatic},
                  ImageSize -> 450]]],
         Button["Export", 
            Export[FileNameJoin[
               {
               $HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "KernedText.png"
               }],
            kernedText],
            ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic}]},
         Right]]]
```

#### Edit

I've cleaned up my code and incorporated kguler's fix. The resulting kerned letters look pretty and export nicely.

[image: kerned text]

Comment: You can use `PlotRange->{{0,10},Automatic}` to fix the issue with the right-most locator. (+1)

Answer (score 7):

First off, `Dynamic[exp]]` redraws whenever anything that appears in expression changes. Think of Manipulate as being just a `Dynamic[code]` with some nice shortcuts to build controllers that can change things that appear in `code`. In your case, you have a `Dynamic[LocatorPane[(* some expression depending on points*)]]`. So whenever someone changes `points` a new locatorpane will be created and displayed right where the old one was, so you won't notice... except that the active controller loses focus, so you stop dragging the controller. Here is a very short demonstration of the problem:

```
points = {{0, 0}};
Dynamic@LocatorPane[Dynamic[points], Graphics[Point /@ points, PlotRange -> 2]]
```

While just moving the `Dynamic` will cause only the graphic to be updated and solve the issue:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[points], Dynamic@Graphics[Point /@ points, PlotRange -> 2]]
```

So how to get around this problem In your case. I would suggest not using `LocatorPane` inside manipulate, and either fully using only manipulate, or going completely without it. Here is a possible solution without using `Manipulate`:

```
text = "Wolfram";
fontsize = 96;
font = "BankGothic";

 DynamicModule[{points = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, Length[Characters[text]]}]},
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[points],
   Column[{
     Button["Export", Export["/tmp/t.png", g]], 
     Dynamic[g = Graphics[{MapIndexed[
     Text[Style[#1, FontSize -> fontsize], points[[First[#2]]]] &,
      Characters[text]]}, ImageSize -> 500]]}]]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks, a good solution. So you don't use `LocatorPane` in `Manipulate`, because it doesn't need to create new panes all the time...

Comment: @cormullion Correct, when it creates a new locator pane, the old locators stop working, so what you where moving stops moving and it redraws.You could possibly also make it all work by using `ControlType->Locator` inside the `Manipulate` and displaying a `Graphics`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the OP has figured the problem out already, so I don't know why I'm bothering except that I think future users might appreciate a good `Manipulate`-based solution as an alternative, especially as an example of how to work with `Locators`.

A few changes:  The most important thing is that the `Locators` are constrained by making the minimum and maximum `y` coordinate the same (`0`).  I used `BaseStyle` instead of styling each character.  For a smoother start-up, I put the font list into the specification for `fonts`; wrapping it in `Dynamic` means that the list of fonts will not be stored in the `Manipulate` output cell, only the code for loading it; since `Manipulate` can't interpret code, I needed to specify the control type.  I changed some of the sizes to scale with `fontsize`.  I also made `text` and `g` local variables.  The important thing about making `text` local is that `points` needs to be initialized after `text` is initialized by the front end, unless it already has been set.  The way `points` might be already initialized is if the cell is copied and pasted, or the notebook reopened.

```
text0 = "Wolfram";
Manipulate[
 g = Graphics[{MapIndexed[Text[#1, points[[First[#2]]]] &, Characters[text]]}, 
   ImageSize -> 0.75 fontsize * (StringLength @ text + 1), 
   PlotRange -> {{0, StringLength @ text + 1}, {-0.7, 1.}},
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> fontsize, FontFamily -> font}],

 {{text, text0}, ControlType -> None}, {g, ControlType -> None},
 {{points, Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, StringLength @ text0}]},
  {0, 0}, {StringLength @ text + 1, 0}, Locator},
 {fontsize, Table[x, {x, 96, 256, 12}]},
 {{font, "Times"}, 
  Dynamic@FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]], 
  PopupMenu},

 Button["Export", Export["/tmp/t.png", g]]
 ]
```

Here's a variation in which the characters themselves are the locators.  Wrapping the characters in `Pane` aligns the text.

```
text0 = "Wolfram";
Manipulate[
 g = LocatorPane[Dynamic@points,
   Dynamic[
    Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> 0.75 fontsize * (StringLength @ text + 1), 
     PlotRange -> {{0, StringLength@text + 1}, {-0.7, 1.}}]
    ],
   {{0, 0}, {StringLength @ text + 1, 0}},
   Appearance -> Pane /@ Characters[text],
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> fontsize, FontFamily -> font}
   ],

 {{text, text0}, ControlType -> None}, {g, ControlType -> None},
 {{points, Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, StringLength @ text0}]}, None},
 {fontsize, Table[x, {x, 96, 256, 12}]},
 {{font, "Times"}, 
  Dynamic@FE`Evaluate[FEPrivate`GetPopupList["MenuListFonts"]], 
  PopupMenu},

 Button["Export", Export["/tmp/t.png", g]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Edit summary:* Apparently I had a definition hanging around that made it seem that the initialization of `points` was working properly in the previous, simpler version.  I've fixed it.  An alternative fix is to initialize `points` in the `Initialization` option, after `text` has been initialized in the front end as follows.  Set `points` to be an empty list in its variable specification, and conditionally initialize it later in `Initialization`.  If it's not conditional, the points will be reset to the beginning whenever the notebook is opened or a copy of the cell is pasted into a notebook (when the `Initialization` code will be executed).

```
{{points, {}}, ...},
...
Initialization :> (If[Length[points] == 0, 
   points = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 1, StringLength @ text}]])
```

(For the ellipsis after `points`, fill in the locator code or `None` in each of the two `Manipulate`s above, as appropriate.)

One could also dispense with the local variable `text` altogether, but I was playing with as an `InputField`, in which case it is convenient for it to be local.

Comment: Cool - this was some time ago! Some interesting additions which I'll check out later. (Necromancer badge for you perhaps?!)

Comment: @cormullion  We'll have to see if more than one person thinks it's cool.  But thanks!